# how to get wordNet lexical categories ( noun categories and verb categories ) using JAWS pacakage

Tags: java, wordnet, jaws-wordnet

If i have array List of words (String). I want to get lexical category of every word. Word Net has noun categories, verb categories and others. I want to get category of each word. How to get this in java using JAWS.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `ReferenceSynset.getLexicalFileNumber`. This will yield an integer that corresponds to a category which are all listed in `man lexnames` man page.

Answer (score 0):

your one word can have multiple categories.
mayb you can try something like :

```
list<Synset> list=database.getSynsets(word);
edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.SynsetType stype = list.get(0).getType()
```